# Evitar Confirmar reenvío del formulario con el Back del navegador

Tags: javascript, html, c#

En mi pagina web me pidieron que haga un boton para volver a la página anterior, lo cual ya tengo terminado y funcionando perfecto.

El problema ahora es que me pidieron que resuelva el problema de "Confirmar reenvío del formulario" cuando vuelvo para atras con el Back del navegador, ya que hay varias personas que están acostumbradas a hacerlo de esa manera y les resulta molesto apretar f5 para reenviarlo (aunque no se esté enviando un formulario, el error me aparece hasta cuando entro al index).

Hay alguna manera de resolver ésto..? Yo hace un tiempo habia leido que no, que haciendo el boton para volver atrás era mejor...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando le das al back del navegador aparece ese error?

Comment: Claro, con un boton que vaya a la pagina anterior funciona bien pero con el back del navegador me pide que refresque la pagina

Comment: Y si desactivas el back del navegador? jeje se puede con JQuery, no sería lo más legal por decirlo así pero funciona.

Comment: No creo que les guste.... es lo que utilizan ellos para volver, me pidieron hacer un boton para volver a la vista anterior pero siguen utilizando el back del navegador.................

Comment: El problema podría solucionarse si el servidor manda un redirect cuando recibe un POST

Comment: Es decir, el problema se soluciona utilizando el patrón Post/Redirect/Get. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get